# AngularJS ng-repeat --Prepending items to array and avoid list data 'jump'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, prepend

I have a 'ng-repeat-able' list I scroll through and need to fix a discrepancy on how the data is shown when I scroll UP (scroll DOWN works). To summarize, I have the 2 scroll (down & up) scenarios below:

**Scroll down works (no 'data jump'):**

When I scroll down to the bottom, the user sees the last 'bottom-item-id' and when new items arrive, I append their array ('.push.apply()') to the bottom of the ng-repeat array (after 'bottom-item-id') and the user properly maintains their position yet still sees the 'bottom-item-id' although the new items are just barely visible under it. Perfect.

**Scroll up works *improperly* ('data jumps') :**

However, when I scroll UP, when new items arrive, I prepend ('unshift.apply()') them to the top of the array.  In this case, if the user were seeing 'top-item-id' prior to prepend, they now see the top most item in the prepended array instead--in other words, the array data 'jumps' up and the user loses their position.

I understand the machinations of how angularjs maintains its internal $index and moves it up on prepending data (unlike appending) which causes the 'data jump'.

I also understand I could apply various 'scroll fixing' or 'anchor scrolling' to keep user's position when user triggers scroll UP.

However, is there an alternative AJS ('simpler') way to maintain the user's position and overcome AJS' $index shift when **prepending** to the ng-repeat array?

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is, maybe there isn't  - How can we tell without seeing the code? Please create a jsfiddle to reproduce the problem

Comment: from what you are describing, this doesn't seem like improper behavior, as much as unanticipated behavior.  the browser view doesn't scroll in either direction when items are added, either to the top or to the bottom.  however, when you add items to the top, *the list itself* changes relative to the browser's position.

Comment: @Claies You are exactly right as I have mentioned. When prepending, AJS adjusts $index up causing this behavior (unlike appending).  Question is how to overcome this in without resorting to the options I cited.

Comment: what alternative would you have that wouldn't involve a "scroll fix"?  the browser view is what has to move, which angular doesn't have a lot of control over....